# DateTimePicker com datas personalizadas

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de marcação de consultas em `Windows Forms` e tive a ideia de incluir um `DateTimePicker` onde apenas as datas com vagas disponíveis devem estar "clicáveis" pelo usuário.

Existe uma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Nunca fiz mas parece que existe uma boa discussão sobre isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319417/disable-some-dates-in-datetimepicker-winform-c-sharp e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361691/how-do-i-disable-some-dates-on-a-datetimepicker-control. A possíveis soluções mostradas nestes tópicos envolvem WPF+ Windows Forms e components de terceiros. Talvez não tenha uma solução nativa e fácil de desabilitar datas específicas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não encontrei uma opção que permita restringir determinadas datas no componente DateTimePicker, talvez você tenha que usar um componente de terceiro para fazer o que deseja como sugerido pelo comentário do @rodrigorf ou criar o seu próprio.

Porém, existe uma alternativa que é manipular o evento [ValueChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.valuechanged.aspx) do componente e verificar as datas que estão sendo selecionadas. Você pode fazer a verificação através de uma lista de datas como esta:

```
public List<DateTime> datasComConsultas = new List<DateTime>();
```

em seguida basta verificar as datas que estão sendo selecionadas no evento `ValueChanged`:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (datasComConsultas.Any(d => d == DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Text))) MessageBox.Show("Esta data nao esta disponivel");
    else MessageBox.Show("Data disponivel");
}
```

Desta forma você pode conferir as datas que não possuem vagas disponíveis ou ao contrário, mas esta não é a maneira perfeita, porem pode lhe ajudar.

Segue o código completo do exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DatePickerExCustom
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public List<DateTime> datasComConsultas = new List<DateTime>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (datasComConsultas.Any(d => d == DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Text))) MessageBox.Show("Esta data nao esta disponivel");
            else MessageBox.Show("Data disponivel");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            datasComConsultas = new List<DateTime>
            {
                new DateTime(2017, 02, 04),
                new DateTime(2017, 02, 05),
                new DateTime(2017, 02, 10)
            };            
        }
    }
}
```

Fonte da solução com base neste [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2366062/5429980).